# Kile: re-fill wrapped paragraph after editing

Tags: wrap, kile, fill

Is there a possibility to refill/reshape a wrapped paragraph after making changes? I configured Kile to hard-wrap after 70 characters, but when I insert or delete words in a paragraph there are sometimes line-breaks after only a few words.
All information I found was only on how to make use of hard or soft wrap, but not on how to fill the line up in this specific editor
In Emacs I solved the problem with m-q to rearrange the whole paragraph after making changes.

Comment: Does unchecking the "Enable static word wrap" (hard-wrap) not help ?

Comment: Tried it, but did not help. Nonetheless I want the text to be wrapped, so I enabled the static word wrap and it wraps the text as intended; but when I edit the text (e.g. delete or add words/sentences) the lines don't fill up again to the adjusted wrap-marker. Enabling and disabling "static word wrap" doesn't rearrange the text.

Comment: A hard-wrap won't be rearranged... for that you have a **Dynamic word wrap** in the "Appearance" menu of Kile's Editor under Settings -> Configure Kile.  See whether [this screenshot tip](https://i.imgur.com/gVMwaKw.png) helps !